# Mongoose add an object to nested array of objects in the database using push method

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

in this function i find the `post` by `post id` then find a specific `comment` within this post by `comment id`, then i check if the nested array of objects `likes` contains `user id`, if no then i push `user id` to `likes` array, otherwise i remove it, but it doesn't work as it doesn't add the `user id` to `likes` array, what's wrong?

```
const likeComment = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const post = await Post.findById(req.body.postId);
    const comment = post.comments.find(
      (comment) => comment.id === req.body.commentId
    );
    if (comment.likes.includes(req.body.userId)) {
      var index = comment.likes.indexOf(req.body.userId);
      if (index !== -1) {
        comment.likes.splice(index, 1);
      }
      res.status(200).json("you disliked this comment");
    } else {
      comment.likes.push(req.body.userId);
      res.status(200).json("you liked this comment");
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

the answer is i need to do `post.save();`